# Getting uncaught exception while using chrome tab query in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to the the current `URL` while binding to short cut keys in chrome , the short cuts key works fine.

In the manifest file i added :

```
permissions" : [
    ..
    "tabs"
  ]
```

here is the code in background.js

```
...
function processURL(url)
 {
    console('Received URL : ' , url);
 }

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
       chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function(tabs){
         var url = tabs[0].url;   
         processURL(url);
         });
      });
```

Here is the error code that i got:

```
Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: object is not a function
    at chrome-extension://fejkdlpdejnjkmaeadiclinbijnjoeei/background.js:58:22              
    extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:9handler 
    extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:9exports.handle            
    extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:15safeCallbackApply 
    extensions::sendRequest:27handleResponse
```

What did i missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `console()`, that actually is an object, so it throws an error. You would call `console.log()` instead:

```
function processURL(url) {
    console.log("Received URL:", url);
}
```